# Migrate Git repository from GCP to AWS

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

What is the best way to move Git  repository with all branches and full history from Google Cloud to AWS cloud ? Is there a script or a list of commands I have to use?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `--mirror` option for `git clone` and `git push`:

```
# clone repository from old location
git clone --mirror git clone old-url/my-repo
cd my-repo

# point the url for `origin` at your new repository
git remote set-url origin new-url/my-repo

# push all references to the new repository
git push --mirror origin
```

Replacing `old-url` and `new-url` with the appropriate repository URLs for your Google Cloud and AWS Cloud repositories.